# Is it possible to multiple phrases to this .py?

Tags: python, twitter, bots

Bot.py ( the one I'm using)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot("/Home/TwitterFollowBot/config.txt")  
my_bot.sync_follows()
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
```

So bacially I'm using this[TwitterFollowBot](https://github.com/rhiever/TwitterFollowBot) bot to automatically retweet any tweet which has "@ShoutGamers" included in it.

Default .py

```
from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot
my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.auto_fav("phrase", count=1000)
```

I would like to know how do I add multiple phrases in to this? 
I need to add these two phrases in to this @ShoutGamers and @RtwtKing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as easy as adding 2 strings.

If you want to auto retweet tweets having both `@ShoutGamers` and `@RtwtKing` in a single tweet you can just:

```
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers @RtwtKing", count=2200)
```

If you want to auto retweet tweets having `@ShoutGamers` and `@RtwtKing` not together you can use `bot.auto_rt()` twice:

```
my_bot.auto_rt("@ShoutGamers", count=2200)
my_bot.auto_rt("@RtwtKing", count=2200)
```